# Bootstrap React Nextjs, doesn't look the same as on the documentation

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap, react, and nextjs for the frontend of my application, and I tried to use the example react-bootstrap example - https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-bootstrap/code-sandbox-examples/tree/master/basic. The result which is supposed to look like: [image: Bootstrap example in code-sandbox] Looks completely different on mine: [image: What my image shows].

Things I have tried:

- Changing from default bootstrap package to bootstrap@next
- importing Bootstrap in the index.jsx file, and in the example.jsx file

Here is the relevant code:
**Example.jsx** - same as codesandbox.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

import React, { useState } from 'react'

import Jumbotron from 'react-bootstrap/Jumbotron'
import Toast from 'react-bootstrap/Toast'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

const ExampleToast = ({ children }) => {
  const [show, toggleShow] = useState(true)

  return (
    <>
      {!show && <Button onClick={() => toggleShow(true)}>Show Toast</Button>}
      <Toast show={show} onClose={() => toggleShow(false)}>
        <Toast.Header>
          <strong className="mr-auto">React-Bootstrap</strong>
        </Toast.Header>
        <Toast.Body>{children}</Toast.Body>
      </Toast>
    </>
  )
}

const App = () => (
  <Container className="p-3">
    <Jumbotron>
      <h1 className="header">Welcome To React-Bootstrap</h1>
      <ExampleToast>
        We now have Toasts
        <span role="img" aria-label="tada">
          
        </span>
      </ExampleToast>
    </Jumbotron>
  </Container>
)

export default App
```

**index.jsx**

```
function HomePage() {
  return <div>Welcome to Next.js!</div>
}

export default HomePage
```

Result of `npm list`:

```
├── bcrypt@5.0.1
├── bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3
├── fastify-cookie@5.3.1
├── fastify-jwt@3.0.0
├── fastify-mongodb@2.0.1
├── fastify-nextjs@5.4.1
├── fastify@3.18.0
├── next@10.2.3
├── nodemon@2.0.7
├── react-bootstrap@1.6.1
├── react-dom@17.0.2
└── react@17.0.2
```

**EDIT:**
If I include bootstrap in index.jsx the result is that the css isn't applied at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that the code-sandbox uses bootstrap 4.6, and I am using bootstrap 5, and when I downgraded to test, it works. (*facepalm*)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install bootstrap for nextJS.

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```

after this installation is complete, please import the css files into the nextJS _app.js

```
// add bootstrap css 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'// own css files here
import "../css/customcss.css";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
      return <Component {...pageProps} />
    }
```

for responsiveness add on your nextjs component the following.

```
<Head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</Head>
```

The other option  is to use a CDN.

Comment: Hi, for me this produces the same mixed result, not sure why this is happening perhaps it is something else?

Comment: did you import the bootstrap.css on your _app.js ?

Comment: know that the path shown in the answer is not the same as on your local path. take that in mind.

Comment: Yes I believe I did, and it produces screenshot #2, and if i don't include it in pages/_app.js it reverts to basic html.

Comment: I am trying to do a minimal example using the code-sandbox which does not appear to have any other features/css files except to center .header, which I implemented, but that still did not change much

Comment: recommend you using npx create-next-app and follow instructions again it works for me.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app/setup

Comment: Ok, last thing, I know it wasn't mentioned in the question (I didn't think it to be relevant) but is it possible that using fastify could be causing this? I am currently handling routes using fastify.next, perhaps I am doing it wrong. If you think this might the case I will edit the question respectively or open another thread. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your network on the browser and check if the bootstrap css is loading.

Comment: can you please tell me the path of your node_modules/ bootstrap location path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234440/discussion-between-aditya-agrawal-and-eddwin-paz).